# How do I get the list that is bound to a ListView as ItemSource?

Tags: wpf, listview, properties

I have a WPF `ListView` which has a `List<T>` as `ItemsSource`.
Now I want to query the list name which is bind to the `ListView`. How do I achieve that?

I need the name of the `List<T>`so I can reuse the function. Example:

```
    private void Sort(ListView lv)
    {
        lv.ItemsSource.Sort((x, y) => y.Name.CompareTo(x.Name)); // does not work
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean that you have access to the `ListView` object and wish to retrieve its `ItemsSource` property? Please add more details and code if possible, the question seems pretty unclear to me.

Comment: @CorentinPane I need to get `List<T> `which is defined as `ItemsSource` so I can sort that particular List

Comment: `ListView.ItemsSource` does give you a reference to the list you are binding to. What about your code "does not work"? You say you need the name of the list; do you mean the name of the variable? Why? Why not just use the reference from `ItemsSource`?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the code here:

https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-sorting/

You will notice you don't need the name of the list to sort it.

**EDIT:
And you can reference a column using just a generic string which seeems to be "Name" in your case.**

The listview works with the default view of what's set or bound to it's itemssource.
You can grab a reference to that and apply sort descriptors.

Code from the link:

```
    public ListViewSortingSample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<User> items = new List<User>();
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42 });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39 });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 13 });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Donna Doe", Age = 13 });
        lvUsers.ItemsSource = items;

        CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvUsers.ItemsSource);
        view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Age", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    }
```

Substitute "Name" for age in that sortdescription and you'll have it sorting on the Name property.

Comment: sorting is by "Name" in the question. +1, using CollectionView is idiomatic for wpf and also solves the issue of updating the view, because even if List is ordered after `Sort()`, it doesn't have notifications and ListView will still display old data

Comment: LOL ! Yes of course I read list name and didn't really look at the OP's code as close as I might have done.

Comment: @ASh sure. But actually I have another function that's called for updating the ListView by calling `lv.ItemsSource = null; lv.ItemsSource = MyList;`

Comment: @B4DschK4Pp, I don't mind if you do it. there are many antipatterns and b4d practices which are still in use

Comment: If you rebuild the list anyhow then why not work with the list rather than the itemssource of the listview? Shrug. Why not use linq orderby on the list? Simpler syntax. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ba3c8e4e-2ca0-4bdb-8af5-bb8ea1b746f2/differences-between-listsort-and-listorderby?forum=csharpgeneral